# Limit size of Android.ImageView

Tags: java, android

Here is my image view:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

But when I set an image to it like this:

```
        final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        iv.setImageBitmap(docPicture);
```

... it fills the screen width. It seems to ignore the MaxWidth and MaxHeight - what am I doing wrong and why is the imageview allowed to exceed its max size?

**Edit:**
Solved by simply adding the ambiguous `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`
Annoyingly I had tried this but set to false - "true" seemed to me to be the problem - that it *was* adjust the boundaries I had set!!

Comment: Look at `adjustViewBounds`

Comment: can you remove the lines android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" and try. Also post a screenshot of how it looks.

Comment: No idea why I couldn't find that question on my original search .... !
That solved it, thanks.